# How to use chrono::DateTime<Utc> with schemars::JsonSchema?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I'm trying to implement `JsonSchema` for a struct like this:

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use schemars::JsonSchema;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Default, Clone, JsonSchema)]
pub struct ArticleResponse {
    pub pub_time: Option<DateTime<Utc>>,
}
```

But this outputs an error when compiling:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `DateTime<Utc>: JsonSchema` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:4:50
   |
 4 | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Default, Clone, JsonSchema)]
   |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `JsonSchema` is not implemented for `DateTime<Utc>`
```

What should I do to implement `JsonSchema` for `ArticleResponse`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote [the docs](https://docs.rs/schemars/latest/schemars/index.html#feature-flags):

> For example, to implement JsonSchema on types from chrono, enable it as a feature in the schemars dependency in your Cargo.toml like so:
>
> ```toml
> [dependencies]
> schemars = { version = "0.8", features = ["chrono"] }
> ```